# What have our users published?

Tags: discussion

What have our users put out in the world recently? And how did Writing.SE help you do it?

Anything published through a traditional publisher or self-published is fine here. (We may refine this after a bit.)

The format for now will be one answer per user.

- Relevant meta thread: [Would publication announcements be appropriate for Meta?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1348/26)

Comment: I think this would be great to be allowable in some way.  Gives users a chance to give a shout out to the help they had from us along the way (arguably inherent self-marketing), but also let us know that we helped someone get closer to their goal.

Answer (score 12):

### Technical writing

A lot of what I've written is proprietary and some is scattered around on my blog (which I'll try to collect later), but meanwhile...

- [Tutorial: Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial)

### Religion books

I am a member of the editorial team and a contributor (not sole author!) for [Mi Yodeya Publications](http://s.tk/miyodeya).  We've published four books so far, about Pesach (Passover), Chanukah, Purim, and the High Holy Days. You can download them at that link.

### Historical research

I am the co-author of *Joy and Jealousy*, a book of reconstructions of 15th-century Italian dances (*balli*).  The book was published on paper in 1997 and later (mostly) posted [online](http://sca.uwaterloo.ca/~praetzel/Joy-J-book/).  The multi-part arrangements of the music weren't integrated into that posting but can be found in [this larger collection](http://sca.uwaterloo.ca/~praetzel/ellisif.html).

### Worldbuilding blog

I've written a bunch of posts for the Worldbuilding.SE blog, Universe Factory, from mid-2015 to present.  Some are fiction, some are how-to or process articles, and some are commentary.

**Process and commentary:**

- [Worldbuilding As You Go: A Case Study](https://medium.com/universe-factory/worldbuilding-as-you-go-a-case-study-8d00665e3a4f)
- [Resurrection of the Dead: Practical Considerations](https://medium.com/universe-factory/resurrection-of-the-dead-practical-considerations-5c65746c3845)
- [When Am I? Navigation for Time Travelers](https://medium.com/universe-factory/when-am-i-dbc905e1ce7b)
- [Meeting the Worldbuilding Designer](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilding-designer-b5fde86de92b), an interview with Stack Exchange designer Kurtis Beavers
- [Building the World of Pangaea](https://medium.com/universe-factory/building-the-world-of-pangaea-d3015cd8485b), about a collaboration edited by Michael Jan Friedman
- *Revelation for RPGs*, a series of posts describing the storytelling and worldbuilding techniques in a role-playing game I played in (and some of the game story along the way).  [First post](https://medium.com/universe-factory/revelation-for-rpgs-ddb32bd91f20),  [index](https://medium.com/@cellio/revelation-for-rpgs-index-df7647e9a690).
- [Why Would They Do That? Discouraging Formal Education](https://medium.com/universe-factory/why-would-they-do-that-discouraging-formal-education-69c5e4fd3f7e)
- [Recovering From Errors: Plugging Loopholes in Your Magic System](https://medium.com/universe-factory/recovering-from-errors-plugging-loopholes-in-your-magic-system-d6c60564c5f0) (based on a Writers.SE question)
- [What do you celebrate? Enriching your culture with unique holidays, and perhaps snowball fights and fondue](https://medium.com/universe-factory/what-do-you-celebrate-128b3e4716ab)
- [Creature Design: Santa Claus](https://medium.com/universe-factory/creature-design-santa-claus-946a9caa6e6)
- [Building Blocks for Worlds: Government](https://medium.com/universe-factory/building-blocks-for-worlds-government-41b90b0c55be)
- [Exploring a Binary Star](https://medium.com/universe-factory/exploring-a-binary-star-d0d1a4671cc1)
- [When Cosmetic Differences Aren't](https://medium.com/universe-factory/when-cosmetic-differences-aren-t-39d058d69b47)
- [The Sisters' War: The Story Behind the Story](https://medium.com/universe-factory/sisters-the-story-behind-the-story-12944abf0d2a)

**Fiction**

- [At the End of the Day](https://medium.com/universe-factory/at-the-end-of-the-day-9a4b62023663) (short-short story, ~500 words)
- *The Sisters' War*, a serialized story, two of three parts published so far.  [Chapter 1](https://medium.com/universe-factory/sisters-a718622d808f), [summary/index](https://medium.com/@cellio/sisters-the-story-so-far-239236265a81).

Answer (score 7):

Below is a list of published Automotive How-To articles I wrote for a company called Internet Brands. These were published between March 2016 to August 2016.

[**Acurazine.com**](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/)

- [Acura TSX: How to Replace Radiator Cooling Fan](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tsx-how-to-replace-radiator-cooling-fan-426731)
- [Acura TSX: How to Replace Thermostat](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tsx-how-to-replace-thermostat-426730)
- [Acura TSX: How to Flush Radiator Coolant](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tsx-how-to-flush-radiator-coolant-426726)
- [Acura TSX: How to Replace Valve Cover Gasket](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tsx-how-to-replace-valve-cover-gasket-426744)
- [Acura TL 2009-2014 and MDX: How to Replace Ignition Coils and Spark Plugs](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-2009-2014-and-mdx-how-to-replace-ignition-coils-and-spark-plugs-423983)
- [Acura TL 2009-2014: How to Replace Starter](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-2009-2014-how-to-replace-starter-423985)
- [Acura TL 2009-2014 and MDX: Why is My Battery Not Charging?](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-2009-2014-and-mdx-why-is-my-battery-not-charging-423994)
- [Acura TL 2009-2014: How to Change the Oil](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-2009-2014-how-to-change-the-oil-423992)
- [Acura TL 2009-2014: How to Replace Air Filter](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-2009-2014-how-to-replace-air-filter-423991)
- [Acura TL 2009-2014 and MDX: How to Replace Serpentine Belt](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-2009-2014-and-mdx-how-to-replace-serpentine-belt-423993)
- [Acura TL 2004-2008: How to Replace Oxygen (O2) Sensor](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-2004-2008-how-to-replace-oxygen-o2-sensor-423885)
- [Acura TL 2004-2008: How to Replace Ignition Coils and Spark Plugs](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-2004-2008-how-to-replace-ignition-coils-and-spark-plugs-423884)
- [Acura TL 2004-2008: How to Replace Timing Belt, Water Pump and Thermostat](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-2004-2008-how-to-replace-timing-belt-water-pump-and-thermostat-423929)
- [Acura TL 2004-2008: How to Replace Air Filter](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-2004-2008-how-to-replace-air-filter-423888)
- [Acura TL 2004-2008: How to Change the Serpentine Belt](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-2004-2008-how-to-change-the-serpentine-belt-423890)
- [Acura TL 2004-2008: How to Change Oil](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-2004-2008-how-to-change-oil-423889)
- [Acura TL: Brake Modifications](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-brake-modifications-424506)
- [Acura TL: How to Replace Brake Fluid](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-how-to-replace-brake-fluid-423917)
- [Acura TL: How to Replace Brake Line](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-how-to-replace-brake-line-424499)
- [Acura TL 2009-2014 and MDX: How to Replace Timing Belt and Water Pump](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-2009-2014-and-mdx-how-to-replace-timing-belt-and-water-pump-423997)
- [Acura TL 2009-2014 and MDX: How to Replace Serpentine Belt](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-2009-2014-and-mdx-how-to-replace-serpentine-belt-423993)
- [Acura TSX: How to Replace Serpentine Belt](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tsx-how-to-replace-serpentine-belt-426749)

[**AudiWorld.com**](https://www.audiworld.com/how-tos/)

- [Audi A4 B8: Information on the Oil Consumption Problem](https://www.audiworld.com/how-tos/a/audi-a4-b8-information-on-the-oil-consumption-problem-421881)
- [Audi A4 B8: How to Change Engine Oil](https://www.audiworld.com/how-tos/a/audi-a4-b8-how-to-change-engine-oil-421882)
- [Audi A6 C6: How to Replace Side Marker Bulb](https://www.audiworld.com/how-tos/a/audi-a6-c6-how-to-replace-side-marker-bulb-421222)
- [Audi A4 B7: How to Repair and Replace Parking Brake](https://www.audiworld.com/how-tos/a/audi-a4-b7-how-to-repair-and-replace-parking-brake-421056)
- [Audi A4 Avant, Q5 and Q7: How to Turn Off the Rear Wiper](https://www.audiworld.com/how-tos/a/audi-a4-avant-q5-and-q7-how-to-turn-off-the-rear-wiper-422191)
- [Audi A4 B7 and A3: Engine Tune Reviews](https://www.audiworld.com/how-tos/a/audi-a4-b7-engine-tune-reviews-421234)
- [Audi A4 B7: How to Replace Low Pressure Fuel Pump (LPFP) on Non-Quattro](https://www.audiworld.com/how-tos/a/audi-a4-b7-how-to-replace-low-pressure-fuel-pump-lpfp-on-non-quattro-421236)
- [Audi A4 B7: How to Replace Low Pressure Fuel Pump (LPFP) on Quattro](https://www.audiworld.com/how-tos/a/audi-a4-b7-how-to-replace-low-pressure-fuel-pump-lpfp-on-quattro-421235)
- [Audi A4 B7: How to Replace EVAP Purge (N80) Valve](https://www.audiworld.com/how-tos/a/audi-a4-b7-how-to-replace-evap-purge-n80-valve-421193)
- [Audi A4 B7: How to Replace Timing Belt and Water Pump](https://www.audiworld.com/how-tos/a/audi-a4-b7-how-to-replace-timing-belt-and-water-pump-420899)
- [Audi A4 B7: How to Replace Air Filter](https://www.audiworld.com/how-tos/a/audi-a4-b7-how-to-replace-air-filter-421189)
- [Audi A4 B7: How to Change Engine Oil](https://www.audiworld.com/how-tos/a/audi-a4-b7-how-to-change-engine-oil-421190)
- [Audi A4 B7/B8: Tires General Information and Specs](https://www.audiworld.com/how-tos/a/audi-a4-b7-b8-tires-general-information-and-specs-421062)
- [Audi A4 B7/B8: How to Replace Brake Pads/Calipers/Rotors](https://www.audiworld.com/how-tos/a/audi-a4-b7-b8-how-to-replace-brake-pads-calipers-rotors-421055)
- [Audi A4 B7/B8: Brake Pad Reviews](https://www.audiworld.com/how-tos/a/audi-a4-b7-b8-brake-pad-reviews-420908)
- [Audi A4 B7: Brake Modifications](https://www.audiworld.com/how-tos/a/audi-a4-b7-brake-modifications-420907)
- [Audi A6 C5: How to Bleed the Clutch](https://www.audiworld.com/how-tos/a/audi-a6-c5-how-to-bleed-the-clutch-421719)
- [Audi A6 C5: How to Replace Transmission Control Module](https://www.audiworld.com/how-tos/a/audi-a6-c5-how-to-replace-transmission-control-module-421720)

[**LS1Tech.com**](https://ls1tech.com/how-tos/)

- [Camaro and Firebird: Brakes Diagnostics Guide](https://ls1tech.com/how-tos/a/camaro-and-firebird-brakes-diagnostics-guide-420806)
- [Camaro, Firebird, and Corvette: LS Engine Cylinder Head Guide and General Information](https://ls1tech.com/how-tos/a/camaro-firebird-and-corvette-ls-engine-cylinder-head-guide-and-general-information-419349)
- [Camaro and Firebird: Why is My Brake Light On?](https://ls1tech.com/how-tos/a/camaro-and-firebird-why-is-my-brake-light-on-420805)
- [Camaro and Firebird: Brake Modifications](https://ls1tech.com/how-tos/a/camaro-and-firebird-brake-modifications-420801)
- [Camaro and Firebird: LS Engine Camshaft Guide and General Information](https://ls1tech.com/how-tos/a/camaro-and-firebird-ls-engine-camshaft-guide-and-general-information-419346)
- [Camaro and Firebird: What You Need to Know About Superchargers and Turbochargers](https://ls1tech.com/how-tos/a/camaro-and-firebird-what-you-need-to-know-about-superchargers-and-turbochargers-419335)
- [Camaro and Firebird: How to Remove Engine from Bottom](https://ls1tech.com/how-tos/a/camaro-and-firebird-how-to-remove-engine-from-bottom-419321)
- [Camaro and Firebird: How to Replace Oil Pressure Sensor](https://ls1tech.com/how-tos/a/camaro-and-firebird-how-to-replace-oil-pressure-sensor-419356)
- [Camaro and Firebird: How to Replace Radiator](https://ls1tech.com/how-tos/a/camaro-and-firebird-how-to-replace-radiator-418004)
- [Camaro and Firebird: How to Flush Radiator Coolant](https://ls1tech.com/how-tos/a/camaro-and-firebird-how-to-flush-radiator-coolant-418006)
- [Camaro and Firebird: Why is My Car Overheating?](https://ls1tech.com/how-tos/a/camaro-and-firebird-why-is-my-car-overheating-418007)
- [Camaro and Firebird: How to Replace Thermostat and Water Pump](https://ls1tech.com/how-tos/a/camaro-and-firebird-how-to-replace-thermostat-and-water-pump-418005)

[**Ford-Trucks.com**](https://www.ford-trucks.com/how-tos/)

- [Ford F150: How to Replace Power Steering Pump](https://www.ford-trucks.com/how-tos/a/ford-f150-how-to-replace-power-steering-pump-429635)

[**NorthAmericanMotoring.com**](https://www.northamericanmotoring.com/how-tos/)

- [Mini Cooper 2001-2006: How to Replace Starter](https://www.northamericanmotoring.com/how-tos/a/mini-cooper-2001-2006-how-to-replace-starter-431061)
- [Mini Cooper 2001-2006: How to Replace Alternator](https://www.northamericanmotoring.com/how-tos/a/mini-cooper-2001-2006-how-to-replace-alternator-431062)
- [Mini Cooper 2007-2013: How to Replace High Pressure Fuel Pump](https://www.northamericanmotoring.com/how-tos/a/mini-cooper-2007-2013-how-to-replace-high-pressure-fuel-pump-431249)
- [Mini Cooper 2001-2006: How to Replace Crankshaft Position Sensor](https://www.northamericanmotoring.com/how-tos/a/mini-cooper-2001-2006-how-to-replace-crankshaft-position-sensor-431065)
- [Mini Cooper 2007-2013: How to Replace the Fuel Filter](https://www.northamericanmotoring.com/how-tos/a/mini-cooper-2007-2013-how-to-replace-the-fuel-filter-431248)

Answer (score 4):

#### Blog Posts in the Universe Factory (WorldBuilding.SE's Blog on Medium)

I have written a few fantasy short stories for the Universe Factory. Most of the time I am using the answers and questions I have written on WorldBuilding.SE as a basis, though there has been one where I mixed some questions from another user with one of my own as the basis.

They are grouped into different series (none of which have a real name yet):

- Kitsuniverse - fantasy magical warfare with antropomorphic foxes

  - [The Ambush Part 1](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-ambush-part-1-404364696d6f)
  - [The Ambush Part 2](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-ambush-part-2-24de4e2ec225)
- Luna's Experiments - dystopian sci-fi/fantasy about genetical engineering

  - [Luna's Experiments: Cat Ears](https://medium.com/universe-factory/lunas-experiments-cat-ears-26d2f01764c)
  - [Luna's Experiments: Wolf Nose](https://medium.com/universe-factory/lunas-experiments-wolf-nose-2683790048d)
  - [Luna’s Experiments: Vacation](https://medium.com/universe-factory/lunas-experiments-vacation-1cafad203e2e)
- Prudus Explains Magic - high fantasy discussions about different variations on *magic*

  - [Prudus Explains Magic: A Wizard's Staff](https://medium.com/universe-factory/prudus-explains-magic-a-wizards-staff-76532a439956)
  - [Prudus Explains Magic: A Wizard's Grimoire](https://medium.com/universe-factory/prudus-explains-magic-a-wizards-grimoire-1da41961e7c3)
- Sebiar - high fantasy discussions about Necromancers and the definitions of *evil*

  - [Sebiar and the adventurers](https://medium.com/universe-factory/sebiar-and-the-adventurers-6ccd8ea7f244)
- Single stories - different questions/answer I found interesting to explore or things I just came up with

  - [Call Of The Night Raven](https://medium.com/universe-factory/call-of-the-night-raven-4e6c9091143b) - mild horror alternate-earth creatures
  - [Heaven's Fall](https://medium.com/@secespitus/heavens-fall-ce451d1f951a) - Heaven can be quite boring after a couple centuries; good thing our protagonist gets some "challengers" in this slightly different utopia
  - [Fenra's Awakening](https://medium.com/universe-factory/fenras-awakening-da8e6a90c43) - slavery in a magical society with a lot of brutal slavery and not so much magic in this short story (***Warning! Mature content that not everyone will be comfortable with. You have been warned!***)

Answer (score 4):

I see from a quick Google search that **Alexandro Chen**, an early, frequent poster of questions here, did in fact (self-) publish the book that he was working on at the time (*[Animal Suicide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1519228686)*), and recently released a follow-up, a collection of short stories.

It also looks like Writing SE legend **Mark Baker** has recently released a book called *[Structured Writing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1937434567)* (XML Press).

**Dale Hartley Emery**, another one of our top 10 users, published [a number of titles](https://www.amazon.com/Dale-Hartley-Emery/e/B00J04NBRQ/ref=dp_byline_cont_book_1) a few years ago, through what appears to be his own private publishing imprint, Driscoll Brook Press.